# How to get group rowIndex in getRowGroup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with grouped rows in the Sheet. I have a couple of groups and I want to get the topic of each group with Google Apps Script.

I've researched [Class Sheet doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRowGroup(Integer,Integer)) and found Method

> getRowGroup(rowIndex, groupDepth)

But still I don't know how to receive rowIndex from the Sheet. Also quantity of groups could be changed and I don't know how to get topic of each group whether expanded or colapsed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're wanting to determine the "topic" for any given row that may be in a row group. I set up an example sheet like this:

[image]

So if you want to know the "topic" for a value in cell(3,1) "Pinot Noir", you want to return the value "Reds" from row 1.

Basically, the `rowIndex` is any row in the sheet. But I believe you're looking for the row where the control is located. To find that row, I've created a function:

```
function findGroupRowIndex(sheet, thisRow) {
  //--- if the given row is a part of a Group, then it will return the
  //    rowIndex (the row with the control) of the group, otherwise it
  //    returns 0
  try {
    var rowGroup = sheet.getRowGroup(thisRow, 1);
    var groupDepth = sheet.getRowGroupDepth(thisRow);
    var index = rowGroup.getControlIndex();
    return index;
  } catch (e) {
    //--- this row is not part of a group
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The important parts of the function are to make sure you are catching any exceptions thrown if the given row is not part of a `rowGroup`.

My whole code module with a calling function is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());

  var lookAtRow = 3;
  var topicRow = findGroupRowIndex(sheet,lookAtRow);
  if (topicRow != 0) {
    Logger.log('topic for group on row ' + lookAtRow + ' is ' + 
                sheet.getRange(topicRow,1).getValue());
  } else {
    Logger.log('no topic exists for row ' + lookAtRow);
  }
}

function findGroupRowIndex(sheet, thisRow) {
  //--- if the given row is a part of a Group, then it will return the
  //    rowIndex (the row with the control) of the group, otherwise it
  //    returns 0
  try {
    var rowGroup = sheet.getRowGroup(thisRow, 1);
    var groupDepth = sheet.getRowGroupDepth(thisRow);
    var index = rowGroup.getControlIndex();
    return index;
  } catch (e) {
    //--- this row is not part of a group
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. Actually the issue was to determine all the groups in the document and then to get their titles. These titles form a list in next step and becoming a "Table of contents".

Comment: Using my example code, you could increment a row counter down a column to find all the top level group rows and form a collection. This will give you your Table of Contents.